# Facebook Stream Posts Missing

Tags: stream, facebook-fql, posts

I was querying fql for all the posts on my wall and trying out different things with it.  I noticed that there were certain posts that were missing.  Just to test it out, I started looking at the "feed" option on the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) (with all possible permissions checked on all three tabs).  I found out that I could not view a particular post either.  My friend and I tested, and he posted a link to my wall.  When he queried the feed on the API explorer, he could see his link.  I however, could not see it.  An additional mutual friend posted a link to my wall, and I could see that new link just fine, but the initial friend could not.

I also noticed with another user, I could see all posts on my wall that were just text, but I could not see any links that they referenced.  I'm not sure if there were any other posts missing as well, but I know that NONE of his links were their.

Is this some strange privacy setting that he has on his posts? I always interpreted that given the right permissions (read_stream) or all permissions I should be able to pull everything on my wall.  However, it seems that I can only pull specific content.  Thanks for any help anyone can give me with this! I want to pull all of the comments that people have on my wall, and I'm just having problems with this.

Comment: Individual Privacy settings will over ride the permissions that a user gives to an app.  EG:  if i only share with friends and i give permissions to your app to read_stream then only my friends that have added the app will see the stream through the app.

Comment: My friend and I had both added the app with all permissions (Graph API explorer).  He shared a post on my wall, so I clearly have permissions to view it (i.e. his individual privacy settings say that I can view it).  Doesn't this fit the situation you just mentioned above?  Shouldn't anything viewable by me be available on the stream, let alone something on my own wall, ESPECIALLY if the poster has also added the app and given read_stream?

Comment: As a test have your other user like the last 10 posts on your wall... Then have that user repost as you did before and then see if it shows up.  This may be related to the priority algorithm facebook uses to show the posts to begin with.  Or try browsing the posts in the explorer using since= and until=

since=5+hours+ago&until=now

Comment: If there's a priority algorithm to show posts or not show posts, why wouldn't it show all posts up to the limit? If I run a FQL command and say LIMIT 500 but it only pulls 300 posts, why would it not show the missing posts? At least in the FQL, limiting by time does not make more posts show up. I feel like there should be some way to just pull everything on your wall, especially for recent posts.